# Should the E-ELT tag get "sent to the cornfield" and replaced by extremely-large-telescope?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tag-synonyms, tagging

When tagging [What two "little observatories" run by a university in Chile and "by Germans" are near the future site of the Extremely Large Observatory?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/45553/7982) I typed "extre..." and saw no appropriate tag so I created

- [extremely-large-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extremely-large-telescope) **1** question

> The extremely-large-telescope tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

Then I though to type "elt" and found

- [e-elt](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e-elt) **4** questions

> Questions about the upcoming European Extremely Large Telescope.

I think that the "E-" prefix has been dropped as (according to the video in the question) they are waiting for money from Brazil, but I'm not sure about that.

**Question:** Should the E-ELT tag get "sent to the cornfield" and replaced by extremely-large-telescope?